# Git + Windows 8 + SSH: Asks for password

Tags: windows, git, windows-8, ssh

I want to clone a remote repository with Git+SSH on Windows 8. But it don't want to accept my Key, it always asks for the password (not passphrase).

I think the problem has to do something with the ssh client, because I tried some other Git-Tools that are also not working (TortoiseGit + Netbeans).

The private SSH-Key is stored under C://Users/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa and C:\Program Files (x86)\Git.ssh\id_rsa. For test cases I also changed the folders to completely writeable.

There is no passphrase, so it normally should connect without asking. But it still asks, also with this command (in Git Bash):

ssh -T git@example.com

Answer: "git@example.com's password:"

I uninstalled everything and tried it with this tutorial: http://danielhuesken.de/git-fur-windows-installieren-und-ssh-keys-nutzen/

Also opened Git SSH-Client as admin, the fingerprint was added to known_hosts.

I already deactivated my security software (eset) but it also does not work. Other people are able to clone the repository (on Mac).

Comment: Can you check in Git Bash the content of `ls $HOME/.ssh` (or `dir %HOME%\.ssh`: do you see `id_rsa` *and* `id_rsa.pub`?

Comment: Is the public key published on the server side in the `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` file?

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! I don't have the direct access to the server. But we are using gitlab and I entered the public key there.

Comment: Make sure you entered the key as one unique line.